# PostgreSQL mode in flow test

Tags: corda

is it possible to use postgresql mode in flow test?
i have try to overwrite datasource.

```
val nodeConfig = MockNodeConfigOverrides(
                extraDataSourceProperties =
                mapOf("dataSource.url"
                        to "jdbc:h2:mem:partya_persistence;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE")
        )
 nodeA = mockNet.createNode(legalName = CordaX500Name("PartyA", "London", "GB"),configOverrides = nodeConfig)
```

but error with startup

```
Unknown data type: "blob"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE public.node_info_party_cert (party_name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ismain BOOLEAN NOT NULL, owning_key_hash NVARCHAR(130), party_cert_binary BLOB) [50004-199] [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE public.node_info_party_cert (party_name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, ismain BOOLEAN NOT NULL, owning_key_hash NVARCHAR(130), party_cert_binary BLOB)] {changeSet=migration/node-info.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-11::R3.Corda, databaseChangeLog=master.changelog.json}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL mode is not supported in the mock node, but you can use Postgres when using driver test. You can check out documentation about is [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/node-database.html#postgresql).

Comment: is it still same the case? or any update ?